# Using javascript variable in jquery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `<form>` with this input...

```
Term ID: <input type="text" name="data_array[0][term_id]" size="5" value="' . $highest_term_id . '">
```

where `$highest_term_id` is set by PHP.

I'm trying to use jquery to increment the "data_array[0]" part by...

```
$("input[data_array[" + index + "][term_id]").val((index + 1));
```

but I get this error:

> Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:
>   input[data_array[undefined][term_id]"

A bit higher in the script I have `var index = 0;`;

Any ideas why this is failing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The square bracket has special meaning in jQuery selectors - you'll have to escape them - should be something like:

```
$("input[name=data_array\\[" + index + "\\]\\[term_id\\]]").val((index + 1));
```

I'd try to avoid this naming convention if possible, or try to find an alternative to selecting it by name - as you can see, it's hard to keep the brackets and backslashes straight when referencing it.

Comment: The error is gone now, but the increment part isn't working.  Thanks for the info about the [ ]s though.

Comment: When you say "increment", you're not incrementing anything here - you're just saying `index + 1`. Are you trying to do `++index`?

Comment: Sorry... yeah.  A bit later in the code I do `index++;`.

Comment: Tried `$("input[data_array\\[0\\]\\[term_id\\]").val();` in Firebug (Firefox) and it's returning null.

Comment: The selector is still wrong - the `data_array[0][term_id]` is the `name` of the tag, so your selector should be looking at name. Look at my example again.

Comment: DOH!!!  Thanks.  I have another problem to deal with now, but that worked.  Thanks.